# Logging Which Columns Have Been Read Or Written To

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a Microsoft SQL Server database with dozens of tables and perhaps thousands of columns. Most of the code that ran queries against the database (read and write) is now out of service (like 80%). I'd like to start deleting those obsolete columns and tables.

Is there any product, command or feature that will allow me to track what columns have been read from, or written to, over a specific time frame? Something that sort of mimics a code coverage report in unit testing? I've seen columns_updated, but it only handles the writes, not the reads for me.

Comment: How about deny select on said objects and set up an Extended Events session to track permission denied errors?

Comment: That might do the trick. Give me a couple of days to test and try to automate capturing the results and I'll post the results.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly what you are looking for but might help:

Have a look at Brent Ozars [sp_BlitzIndex](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/):

```
exec sp_BlitzIndex
     @DatabaseName='AdventureWorks2012',
     @mode=2;
GO
```

It will show you date and time of the last seeks, scans, lookups and update on your indexes (and much more).

Comment: I believe it's gonna be limited to get info since the last restart of the SQL Server instance, so if his instance was rebooted last week and a table was queried last month, the OP could remove that table. But if the instance hasn't been rebooted for a long time, it could be helpful as you mentioned.

Comment: @Ronaldo this is true, thought it was obvious. Maybe I should've mentioned it.

Comment: Although this community is composed of seasoned DBAs, it's also frequently visited by users with little experience that are not aware of those obvious details and are eager to try and fix their problems ASAP, thus not seeking any further info about what is proposed on the received answers, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks to Manu for the lead. Like you say its not quite what I need but it's still looks like a super useful tool. I've done a lot of research and there doesn't seem to be any tool that does what I outlined. But I want to thank Ronaldo for pointing out that I didn't get back to you the next day and that it's a clear sign of 'little experience'. I'll let my mother's oncologist know I need to start focusing on other things.